# Vector error : The type of this term is a product

Tags: coq, dependent-type, convoy-pattern

I want last k elements of vector. I wrote this code with reference to [Coq.Vectors.VectorDef](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.VectorDef.html).

```
 Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.

 (* vector of R *)
 Inductive Euc:nat -> Type:=
 |RO : Euc 0
 |Rn : forall {n:nat}, R -> Euc n -> Euc (S n).

 Notation "[ ]" := RO.
 Notation "[ r1 , .. , r2 ]" := (Rn r1 .. ( Rn r2 RO ) .. ).
 Infix ":::" := Rn (at level 60, right associativity).

 (* return length of vector *)
 Definition EucLength {n}(e:Euc n) :nat:= n.

 Definition rectEuc (P:forall {n}, Euc (S n) -> Type)
 (bas: forall a:R, P [a])
 (rect: forall {n} a (v: Euc (S n)), P v -> P (a ::: v)) :=
 fix rectEuc_fix {n} (v: Euc (S n)) : P v :=
 match v with
 |@Rn 0 a v' =>
   match v' with
     |RO => bas a
     |_ => fun devil => False_ind (@IDProp) devil
   end
 |@Rn (S nn') a v' => rect a v' (rectEuc_fix v')
 |_ => fun devil => False_ind (@IDProp) devil
 end.

 (* eliminate last element from vector *)
 Definition EucElimLast := @rectEuc (fun n _ => Euc n) (fun a => []) (fun _ a _ H => a ::: H).

 (* this function has an error *)
 Definition rectEucLastN (P:forall {n}, nat -> Euc n -> Type)
 (bas: forall {n} k (e:Euc n), P k e)
 (rect: forall {n} k a (e:Euc (S n)), P k e -> P (S k) (a ::: e)) :=
 fix rectEuc_fix {n} (k:nat) (e:Euc n): P k e :=
 match k,e with
 |S k', e' ::: es => rect k' e' (rectEuc_fix k' (EucElimLast ((EucLength e)-1) e))
 |0%nat, e' ::: es => bas k e
 |_, _ => fun devil => False_ind (@IDProp) devil
 end.
```

`rectEucLastN` says `The type of this term is a product while it is expected to be (P ?n@{n1:=0%nat} ?n0@{k1:=0%nat} ?e@{n1:=0%nat; e1:=[]}).`

The problem is the second line from the bottom of the code.

Why does last pattern have an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function term that you see on the branch of `rectEuc` is how you tell Coq that a pattern-match branch is contradictory. In your first recursive function, for instance, you use it to say that the first `v'` cannot be a cons because its length is zero.  The reason you are getting the error in the last branch is because that case is *not* contradictory: nothing in the type of your function prevents the case  `k = 0` and `n = 0`.

To write dependently typed programs over indexed families, you often need to use the *convoy pattern*: to refine the type of an argument `x` after branching on some expression, your `match` needs to return a function that abstracts over `x`. For instance, this function computes the last element of a vector by recursion over its length. In the `S` branch, we need to know that the length of `v` is connected to `n` somehow.

```
Definition head n (v : Euc (S n)) : R :=
  match v with
  | x ::: _ => x
  end.

Definition tail n (v : Euc (S n)) : Euc n :=
  match v with
  | _ ::: v => v
  end.

Fixpoint last n : Euc (S n) -> R :=
  match n with
  | 0   => fun v => head 0 v
  | S n => fun v => last n (tail _ v)
  end.
```

Here is the code for extracting the last `k` elements. Note that its type uses the `Nat.min` function to specify the length of the result: the result cannot be larger than the original vector!

```
Fixpoint but_last n : Euc (S n) -> Euc n :=
  match n with
  | 0   => fun _ => []
  | S n => fun v => head _ v ::: but_last n (tail _ v)
  end.

Fixpoint snoc n (v : Euc n) (x : R) : Euc (S n) :=
  match v with
  | [] => [x]
  | y ::: v => y ::: snoc _ v x
  end.

Fixpoint lastk k : forall n, Euc n -> Euc (Nat.min k n) :=
  match k with
  | 0 => fun _ _ => []
  | S k => fun n =>
    match n return Euc n -> Euc (Nat.min (S k) n) with
    | 0 => fun _ => []
    | S n => fun v =>
      snoc _ (lastk k _ (but_last _ v)) (last _ v)
    end
  end.
```

Personally, I would advise you against programming in this style in Coq, since it makes it difficult to write programs and understand them later. It is usually better to write a program without dependent types and prove after the fact that it has some property that you care about. (E.g. try to show that reversing a list twice yields the same list using vectors!) Of course, there are cases where dependent types are useful, but most of the time they are not needed.

Comment: Is it possible to prohibit arguments with k > n in `lastk` ?
I want only output whose type is `Euc k`.